# Python read_csv tokenizing error / Reading from an inconsistent csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sqlalchemy

I have a csv file that has a few hundred rows and 13 columns. The csv file is structured as follows (example):

```
a  b  c  d 

23 43 54 65

76 23 43 63

.

.

a  b  e  c  d

21 12 43 12 09 

23 12 32 43 87
```

Values of one header appear under another header. As a result, when I use read_csv, I get ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 12 fields in line 27458, saw 13.

Any suggestions on how I can clean/rearrange the csv file and put the right column values under the right column? Maybe create a new csv or input it into a db. tHANKS

Comment: Are you sure the csv is clean ?
Have you checked the row 27458 and is there really 1 more column than it should have ?

Comment: It sounds like you don't really have "a csv file" *per se*, you have multiple csv files that have been appended together and stored in a single disk file. You'll probably need to do some pre-processing on the original file to split the disparate csv "chunks" into separate files, import them individually so the columns don't get messed up (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58467726/python-read-csv-tokenizing-error-reading-from-an-inconsistent-csv-file#comment103270752_58467880)), and then merge them together into a single DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't particularly need to create a dataframe then you can deal with this easily by not using pandas. The standard csv module will happily read lines of different length. Each line is returned as a list. You can either use these directly or if you need to clean up the csv you can append empty strings to the lists so they are all the same length and write them back to a new file.

```
import csv

with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    rdr=csv.reader(f)
    for i in rdr:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide column names(total **13**) in **csv** file as first line of the file, you will be able to use **read_csv** which will return a data with null wherever no value is given and then you can replace **NaN** with any other value you want.

Comment: Good idea, except that the question suggests that the file starts out with n columns [a, b, c, d] and then at some point in the file it inserts an additional column in the middle [a, b, e, c, d]. Trying to use `read_csv` in a single pass would fail because the first part of the file would read "c" values into column[2] but then once the new column was added it would be reading "e" values into column[2] and "c" values into column[3].